# async await javascript

Tags: javascript, html, promesas

La primera se ejecuta de primero y se encarga de leer el html para guardar datos en un **array bidimensional** (javascript), pero antes de guardar el dato en el `array` deseo validarlo si es `null` o **vacío** (hasta aqui sin problemas).

Para esto uno `asyn` y `await`. Como son varias columnas a guardar en mi `array` uso varios `await` *para validar dato por dato*, pero mi problema es que **solo funciona el `await` de la primera validación** y como que se no avanza más el software.

Esta es mi primera función:

```javascript
for(var a=0;a<elementos_variantes.length; a++)
{
    datos[a]= new Array();
}

// Recopilacion de datos
for(var b=0;b<elementos_variantes.length; b++)
{
    datos[b][0]=await validar_datos($("." + elementos_variantes[b] +  '.select_bodega').val());
    datos[b][1]=await validar_datos($("." + elementos_variantes[b] +  '.select_producto').val());
    datos[b][2]=await validar_datos($("." + elementos_variantes[b] +  '.select_variante').val());
    datos[b][3]=await validar_datos($('.ca' + elementos_variantes[b]).val());
}
```

Esta es la función que valida dato por dato :

```javascript
function validar_datos(dato)
{  
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        if(dato=='undefined' || dato==null || dato=="")
        {
            Swal.fire({
                icon: 'error',
                title: 'Informacion',
                text: 'Llene todos los datos.'
            });

            return;
        }
        else
        {
            return dato;
        }
    });
}
```

Como antes mencioné **solo hace la primera validación** a pesar de que el primer dato a validar no es ni `null`, ni `undefined` ni **vacio**, solo valida esta:

```javascript
datos[b][0]=await validar_datos($("." + elementos_variantes[b] +  '.select_bodega').val());
```

y allí se para y no sigue con las validaciones siguientes.

Comment: A mi me da este error en consola al probar tu código:  `SyntaxError: await is only valid in async functions, async generators and modules`.  No se como funciona await, pero parece que no le gusta eso que haces.  Míralo tu mismo aqui: https://jsfiddle.net/j4mqsdwy/

Comment: No entiendo porque crees que es necesario hacerlo asíncrono.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tentativamente, en validaciones sincronas, que no es tu caso, deberia ser como dice Pablo Lozano. Si tu caso es una prueba y al final lo que quieres es trabajar codigo asincrono dentro de la validación deberia ser asi:

```js
async function validar_datos(dato) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    if (dato == 'undefined' || dato == null || dato == "") {
      Swal.fire({
        icon: 'error',
        title: 'Informacion',
        text: 'Llene todos los datos.'
      });

      return reject()
    } else {
      return resolve(dato);
    }
  });
}
```

Mencionar que es necesario que captures el error con un try-catch.

Answer (score 1):

Cuando creas la promesa, has de pasarle una función que a su vez recibe como parámetro la función resolve, que has de llamar para "completar" la promesa. Nunca llamas a dicha función.
De hecho, el código dentro de la promesa es síncrono, no necesitas crear una promesa para nada